# Network Provider and Gps Provider while retrieving Locations

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am developing an app that uses location services.

Now there are two ways the device can get location. The first is via the GPS and the other is via the WIFI/Cell Towers.

We can access those using these two methods.

```
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

my questions is, if the GPS is turned of, but the WIFI/CELLTOWER is on, it sometimes takes around 3-5 minutes until you get a new location (assume you are driving on the highway). Is there any way to dig deeper and check if the result can be retrieved using the WIFI or the CELL TOWER seperately. Or the android system takes care of these and picks the best one, and these two come together ?

Comment: I'm not aware of an ability to know if the location comes from WIFI or cell tower. The idiomatic way to find the location can be found at http://android.codota.com/scenarios/527f779fda0a9d730f8bbc79/android.location.LocationManager?tag=antelope

You may use Location.getAccuracy() to know the accuracy level of the location you got.

Comment: If you target only Google Play market, consider using new location APIs from Google: http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html